# Electron webview's setWindowOpenHandler is not called at all when opening a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, electron, chromium

My Electron (v22.3.6) app uses `<webview>` tag.

This **webview** is located in the **'main.html'** renderer process with `<webview>` tag.

And the **'main.html'** is loaded by `mainWindow`, a `BrowserWindow` variable, in the main process.

Snippets of the code:

**main.html**

```
<webview id="wv" src="inner.html"></webview>
```

**inner.html**

```
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">New window link inside inner.html</a>
```

**main.js**

```
let winOpts = {
    ...
    webPreferences: {
        plugins: false,
        nodeIntegration: false,
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
        webviewTag: true,
        sandbox: false, // to use some components
        enableRemoteModule: false,
        contextIsolation: true,
        disableBlinkFeatures: "Auxclick",
        webSecurity: true,
        preload: "preload.js"
    }    
};

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(winOpts);
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((handler) => {
    //NOT CALLED AT ALL
    return {
        action: "allow"
    };
});

mainWindow.loadFile("main.html");
```

**Problem:**

When I click the link inside the 'inner.html', `<a href="newsite" target="_blank">link</a>`,
nothing happens. Even '**console**' in DevTools shows nothing.
The 'click' behavior seems to trigger nothing.

[image: Scheme]

In the above figure,
clicking the "Main Link" successfully calls `setWindowOpenHandler`.
clicking the "Inner Link" does nothing. Neither opening a new window nor calling `setWindowOpenHandler`.

To sum up, "_blank" target link is not working inside `<webview>` which is in a `BrowserWindow`. `setWindowOpenHandler` is not called.

Comment: You need to call `mainWindow.show()` somewhere. (In the code above, you're also using both `mainWindow` and `mainWin`, make sure to fix that first.)

Comment: @ErikJ thanks. that was a typo. `mainWindow.show()` for the function `setWindowOpenHandler`? cause the mainWindow is working fine.

Comment: OK, then it's fine, I just didn't see the `show()` call in the code you posted.

The Electron docs state "The webview tag is essentially a custom element using shadow DOM to wrap an iframe element inside it.", so I guess that's why it doesn't work. The `mainWindow.webContents` on which you call `setWindowOpenHandler` is not the webContents of the embedded webview. It would have its own separate webContents. I guess you'd need to post some message from the embedded webview out to its parent for this to work.

Comment: @ErikJ Yes, that's probably the reason why the function is not triggered by `webview`. Thus, in that case, I need a solution to 'message' from the `webview` to the main process when a 'new window' is about to open. I couldn't find any `webContents` alternatives in `webview`. Also, couldn't find the proper `addEventListner` in the renderer processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found out how to:**

1. `<webview>` should be with `allowpopups` like `<webview allowpopups></webview>`
2. In the 'main process', there should be a listener for newly generated `webContents`. And, attach the `setWindowOpenHandler` to the `webview`'s `webContents` in that listener function.

```js
    app.on('web-contents-created', (e, wc) => {
        // wc: webContents of <webview> is now under control
        wc.setWindowOpenHandler((handler) => {
            return {action : "deny"}; // deny or allow
        });
    });
```

**Explanation:**

1. `setWindowOpenHandler` only works with `webContents`.
2. `webview`'s `webContents` should be accessed from the main process.
3. there is no direct way to access the `webContents` in renderer processes, and no need to use preload scripts for this.
4. `app.on('web-contents-created')` can detect new `webContents` when a new `webview` is generated in the renderer process, and the very `webContents` is responsible for monitoring new window links (target="_blank" or window.open).

No need for any security-vulnerable settings.

Comment: after a long time internet searching, this was what finally worked for me. thank you!